# Not sure how to deploy puppeteer to heroku when using heroku to host a bot

Tags: heroku, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I have a bot command which is an image scraper, and it uses puppeteer. I have the puppeteer files downloaded into my VSC(Visual Studio Code) and when I run the bot from the VSC terminal, the image scraper function works. I can commit the files that I use onto GitHub, which is then linked to Heroku. But when I try to host the bot on Heroku and use the image scraper command, Heroku gives *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!* I have also added the puppeteer buildpack to my heroku project as well, and that doesn't seem to fix the problem. One solution I've seen is adding { args: ['--no-sandbox'] } to the code, but I'm not sure where to add it. Where can I add the --no-sandbox, or is there another fix to this problem? Thanks

Image Scraper code:

```
var Scraper = require('images-scraper');

const google = new Scraper({
    puppeteer: {
        headless: true
    }
})



module.exports = {
    name: 'image',
    description: 'sends img to channel',
    async execute(client, message, args){
        const image_query = args.join(' ');
        let rng = Math.round(Math.random()*10)
        if(!image_query) return message.channel.send('Unable to find image');

        const image_results = await google.scrape(image_query, 100);
        message.channel.send(image_results[rng].url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit (for image-scraper)

You can use all puppeteer.launch options as normal, with the puppeteer option. You can do it like this.

```js
const google = new Scraper({
    puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
        args: ["--no-sandbox"],
    },
});
```

You can read more about using image-scraper on Heroku [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images-scraper#heroku).

## Previous (for puppeteer)

As you mentioned you can add `--no-sandbox` argument to your code like this.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
  ],
});
```

You can read the puppeteer.launch documentation [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions).

If this doesn't help you, you should check out the official [troubleshooting guide on running Puppeteer on Heroku](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku).

Comment: Where would I add it to my image scraper code, since when I tried to add it under the google declaration it gave me a syntax error error. 
*const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*

Comment: @botcoder updated the answer to fit your need.